# Column aggregation between multiple databases using Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine

Let's say I have 2 tables in different databases that represent one model
(one-to-one column aggregation).

schema:

```
Table1:
  connection: conn1
  columns:
    property1: string
Table2:
  connection: conn2
  columns:
    table1_id: integer
    property2: string
  relations:
    Table2:
      local: table1_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
      foreignType: one
```

So I can retrieve doctrine collection from one table:

```
$objects = Doctrine::getTable('Table1')->findAll()
```

And then retrive properties of each object from another table:

```
foreach ($objects as $object) 
{
  $object->getProperty2();
}
```

But, this will result in too many sql requests from Table2 (one request for each object).
What I'm trying to achieve is one sql request from each table.

If both tables where in one database, a simple join would do the trick. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone intrested, here's a solution: basically you need to execute 2 separate queries resulting in 2 separate result sets, and then join them, using Doctrine_Collection::populateRelated() method.

```
$res_set1 = Doctrine::getTable('Table1')->findAll()
$res_set2 = Doctrine::getTable('Table2')
  ->createQuery('t')
  ->whereIn('t.table1_id', $res_set1->getPrimaryKeys())
  ->execute();

$res_set1->populateRelated('Table2', $res_set2);
```